# Smartkey rekey making multiple copies question

Tags: lock, deadbolt

So I just installed smartkey door lock and deadbolt.  I want to use my door lock to open the deadbolt lock and I followed the rekey instruction to make the door lock key open the deadbolt key. No sweat.  As expected, the original deadbolt key no longer works after the rekey.

Issue is on how to make more than one copy.  Kwikset says we can rekey multiple times.  But if the original deadbolt key does not work anymore after the re-key so how do I make a second copy or more?

Comment: Rekey and copy should be two different functions.  You need to ask about copying the key.  Kwikset should have instructions for making copies.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused -- are you asking about copying the key to have multiple keys, or are you asking about re-keying a third lock?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I am able to rekey a third lock with no probLem.  Now I have a “master” key that works with all door locks.  Question is how do I make a copy of that master key.

Comment: @crip659 thanks.  Looks like I need to call them tomorrow.  Given that Kwikset advertises this product as something you can use to not just rekey but make a copy of the key as well for family members, they should have a video demo to show how to copy the key.

Comment: same way that you make a copy of any key ... take the key to a locksmih and ask for copies ... the smartkey rekeying has nothing to do with your question

Comment: This question needs a serious [edit] to clarify what's being asked. Rekeying a "smart lock" and making duplicates of a key are two _very_ distinct procedures that have absolutely nothing to do with one another. And I'm _very_ confused where the "Master" key mentioned in the comment comes from and what it's got to do with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ever have a briefcase or combination lock where you can change the combination via a procedure?  And once you do, the new combination IS the combination, and the old one doesn't work anymore.  That's all there is to a Kwikset so-called "smart lock".  There are no smarts. So once the new key-cut is learned, the old key-cut no longer works.

Keys have a "cut".  It's the jagged side of them.  If you look closely at different keys, they have different cuts.  Kwikset uses 5 cuts with 7 possible depths of cut.   You can look at two keys and see whether they have the same cut or not.

Remember the Kwikset locks can only be set to work with one cut.   So everyone's key needs to have the same cut.

Inventory all the keys you have, sort them by cut so each group of keys has the same cut.  Once you find a cut that you have enough keys for, re-key your locks to use it.

The Kwikset "smart lock" does not manufacture cut keys.  That requires metal-working, although it's an easy job for anyone with a key-cutting machine. A locksmith, or a hardware store, a drugstore, or even some automated kiosks seen at big-box stores. They typically take a key you already have and make a copy of it.  Though at a better shop if you said "Surprise me!" they could make you a random cut of key.

Answer (score 3):

Most hardware stores have the equipment to copy keys as do locksmiths. Take the key in and tell them how many copies you want.